# Symfony, not whole form cleared

Tags: php, symfony

I have a problem with my registration form, when i click the submit button the registration is done, but not all values of the form are cleared, the password field always have 3 dots in it. What could be the reason?

Comment: It could be password auto-filling provided from the browser - anyway you should provide more details [e.g. browser used].

Comment: I use firefox 17.0.1 . I think you are right, i test it on explorer and its not filled. What can i do to disable it on ff?

Comment: Dunno, but now you have a clue on what to search for ^^

Comment: Ok, thanks. I did't expect that the problem would be the browser.

Comment: Could also be a [placeholder](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder) perhaps?  Believe there are some browser compatibility aspects with it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="password" autocomplete="off" name="field" />
```